# Google spreadsheet Conditional Formatting rows depending on dates on current and another sheet

Tags: spreadsheet, vlookup, conditional-formatting

So I have **Sheet1** and **Sheet2** (in one spreadsheet) where:
Sheet1 contains data from A:E
Sheet2 contains data from A:K

I need to lookup the Sheet1 B cells text in Sheet2 A cells and return Sheet2 J column value (which contains dates) and if Sheet2 date < TODAY then conditional formatting should apply.

I used this formula for conditional formatting:

```
VLOOKUP($B:$B,Sheet2!$A:$K,10,0)<TODAY()
```

This works well if I want to use it just to show the values but **conditonal formatting are not applying to cells**

---

Update:

I tried it with a simpler function. I have added the dates to the F column and used the following conditional formatting formula:

```
F:F<TODAY()
```

**Still doesn't work.**

*PS: I made sure the formats are set to DATE where DATEs are present.*

Answer (score 0):

Try [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) function according to [advanced conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) description:

> Note: Formulas can only reference the same sheet, using standard
>   notation "(='sheetname'!cell)." To reference another sheet in the
>   formula, use the INDIRECT function.